# How to convert <node/> to <node></node> with libxml (converting empty elements to start-end tag pairs)

Tags: c, xml, libxml2, canonicalization

While generating an XML content, I get an empty node `<node/>`, and I want it to be `<node></node>`. (Since `<node></node>` is the correct form of c14n, the progress called "converting empty elements to start-end tag pairs")

How should I convert it?

There's a way hinted by Jim Garrison(Thank you) to do this,
 by using xmlBufferCreate, xmlSaveToBuffer, xmlSaveDoc, xmlSaveClose
with xmlSaveOption: XML_SAVE_NO_EMPTY

Comment: Do you mean how, as in, something like String manipulation?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's some kind of function supported by libxml to do this? Since libxml can do c14n, there should be one handling this situation, or maybe I miss something when producing the node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [libxml2 preserve empty tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423839/libxml2-preserve-empty-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another way which is easier when the nodes are generated under control, by simply giving value "" to the node.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the libxml2 documentation, specifically [xmlSaveOption](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlsave.html#xmlSaveOption) value `XML_SAVE_NO_EMPTY`